# getting error while using Set To Dictionary keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Getting error while using Set To Dictionary keyword in robot framework

Code:

```
  Set To Dictionary ${Data Provider}    name    Sujit
```

I am getting following error while using Set To Dictionary Keyword

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 5):

Your `${Data Provider}` variable needs to be a dictionary, not a string. Provided that you've imported the Collections library, you can declare a dictionary with the `Create Dictionary` keyword.

Example:

```
${Data Provider}    Create Dictionary
Set To Dictionary   ${Data Provider}    name    Sujit
Log                 ${Data Provider}
```

You can also initialise a dictionary with values directly:

```
${Data Provider}    Create Dictionary   name    Sujit
Log                 ${Data Provider}
```

Both of these examples would log `INFO : ${Data Provider} = {u'name': u'Sujit'}`. Find more information about the Collections library here: http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/Collections.html?r=2.8.5

Comment: Thanks For your answer Laurent,but the same way I did this as you mentioned. I already declared that ${Data Provider} as dictionary using 'Create Dictionary' Keyword.but getting above error while setting that dictionary using Set To Dictionary keyword.

Comment: this is a broken link

Answer (score 3):

Mind your spaces after keywords

```
Set To Dictionary      ${Data Provider}     name     Sujit
```